# Write a Prolog query with arity 2 to return the first n numbers of a Lucas sequence in a list

Tags: prolog

It needs to return a list of all the [Lucas numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number) up to the one given, I just have to fill in these two blanks for it to work but I can't seem to figure that out

```
lucas(0, []):-!.
lucas(1, [2]):-!.
lucas(2, [2, 1]):-!.
lucas(N,L) :-
    Y is N-1,
    lucas(Y, X),
    append(_, [A,B], X),
    C is completeHere,
    append(completeHere).
```

Answer (score 0):

That first use of append will get the last two things in a list into A and B:

```
?- append(_, [A,B], [cow,dog,cat,sheep,fox]).
A = sheep,
B = fox
```

Wikipedia says:

> The Lucas series has the same recursive relationship as the Fibonacci sequence, where each term is the sum of the two previous terms,

so there lucas(Y, X) an (annoyingly named) variable X has the previous terms, and A, B now have the two previous terms, so you can calculate `C is ...` using those.

Then you need to `append` the new calculated C (as a list `[C]`) onto the previous terms, to get the new L.